# BeautifulSoup4 : Ampersand in text

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a problem using BeautifulSoup4... (I'm quite a Python/BeautifulSoup newbie, so forgive me if i'm dumb)

Why does the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup_ko = BeautifulSoup('<select><option>foo</option><option>bar & baz</option><option>qux</option></select>')
soup_ok = BeautifulSoup('<select><option>foo</option><option>bar and baz</option><option>qux</option></select>')

print soup_ko.find_all('option')
print soup_ok.find_all('option')
```

produce the following output:

```
[<option>foo</option>, <option>bar &amp; baz</option>]
[<option>foo</option>, <option>bar and baz</option>, <option>qux</option>]
```

i was expecting the same result, an array of my 3 options... but BeautifulSoup seems to dislike the ampersand in the text? How can i get rid of this and get a correct array without editing my HTML (or by transforming/converting it)?

thanks,

**Edit:** Seems like a 4.2.0 bug... i downloaded both 4.2.0 and 4.2.1 versions (from http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.2/beautifulsoup4-4.2.0.tar.gz and http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.2/beautifulsoup4-4.2.1.tar.gz), unzip it in my script folder, change my code to:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "beautifulsoup4-" + sys.argv[1])
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, __version__

print "Beautiful Soup %s" % __version__
soup_ko = BeautifulSoup('<select><option>foo</option><option>bar & baz</option><option>qux</option></select>')
print soup_ko.find_all('option')
```

and got the results:

```
15:24:38 pataluc ~ % python stack.py 4.2.0
Beautiful Soup 4.2.0
[<option>foo</option>, <option>bar &amp; baz</option>]
15:24:41 pataluc ~ % python stack.py 4.2.1
Beautiful Soup 4.2.1
[<option>foo</option>, <option>bar &amp; baz</option>, <option>qux</option>]
```

so i guess my question is closed. thanks for your comments who made me realize it was a version issue.

Comment: a bare `&` in HTML is invalid.

Comment: i get that, but if i replace "&" by "&amp;" in soup_ko i get the same 2 results only...

Comment: Actually, the `&amp;` does seem to be irrelevant. I can't reproduce your problem with either the bare `&` or `&amp;`--either way shows 3 elements. (BS 4.0.5)

Comment: That's true, the code works as expected. I thought the question was about ampersand being replaced.

Comment: how do i check my BS version? i think i have BS4.2

Comment: See `bs4.__version__`. For the record: I'm testing with 4.1.3.

Comment: got it. It seems like a 4.2.0 bug (although i did not find a ticket), i downloaded 4.2.1 and it's solved... i edit my first post to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the edited first post, it was a bug in BeautifulSoup 4.2.0, i downloaded 4.2.1 and the bug is gone.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is used in HTML to input so called *HTML entities*. E.g., `<` is a special symbol in HTML because it starts a tag, so you use `&lt;` instead.

Thus, `&` itself is also a special symbol, and you should use `&amp;` for a literal ampersand. Your HTML was invalid and BeautifulSoup fixed it.

Comment: same answer as for Wooble... still 2 result with valid HTML replacing "&" "&amp;"... :(

Comment: @pataluc That's hard to believe… I can't reproduce it and I have no idea how this could happen. Please, check your code again…

Answer (score 1):

As written before & is part of HTML language, but you can use html.escape before the BeautifulSoup and html.unesacpe afterwards if necessary