# Beautiful Soup turns S&P into S&P; AT&T into AT&T; ?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-entities

I'm parsing some rather messy HTML documents using BeautifulSoup 4 (4.3.2) and am running into a problem where it'll turn a company name like `S&P` (Standard and Poors) or `M&S` (Marks and Spencer) `AT&T` into `S&P;`, `M&S;` and `AT&T;`. So it wants to complete the `&[A-Z]+` pattern into an html entity, but doesn't actually use an html entity lookup table since `&P;` is not an html entity.

How do I make it not do that, or do I just need to regex match the invalid entities and change them back?

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('AT&T announces new plans')
>>> soup.text
u'AT&T; announces new plans'

>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('AT&TOP announces new plans')
>>> soup.text
u'AT&TOP; announces new plans'
```

I've tried the above on OSX 10.8.5 Python 2.7.5 and Scientifix Linux 6 Python 2.7.5

Comment: What version are you running? It appears that this is a known bug in 4.2.0 that was resolved in 4.2.1: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17168523/231316

Comment: @ChrisHaas running version 4.3.2

Comment: Using your minimal example on Ubuntu 13.10 and bs4 `4.3.2` I can not reproduce this problem.

Comment: What parser is it using?

Comment: Why are you feeding it broken input?

Comment: @Random832 I'm not entirely sure, I don't have `lxml` or `html5lib` installed so I'm guessing it's using `HTMLParser.HTMLParser`. How would I find this out?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It doesn't make much of a difference if I do `bs4.BeautifulSoup("<html><body>AT&T bla bla</body></html>")`

Comment: The "&" is broken, not the lack of HTML.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams be that as it may that IS the data I have

Comment: Then unfortunately you don't have a valid HTML document, and you need to get the source to fix their output.

Comment: I have the same problem with BeautifulSoup version 3.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug or feature in the way BeautifulSoup4 handles unknown HTML entity references. As Ignacio says in the comment above, it would be probably be better to pre-process the input and replace the '&' symbols with HTML entities ('&amp;').

But if you don't want to do that for some reason - the only way I could only find a way to fix the problem was by "monkey-patching" the code. This script worked for me (Python 2.73 on Mac OS X):

```
import bs4

def my_handle_entityref(self, name):
     character = bs4.dammit.EntitySubstitution.HTML_ENTITY_TO_CHARACTER.get(name)
     if character is not None:
         data = character
     else:
         #the original code mishandles unknown entities (the following commented-out line)
         #data = "&%s;" % name
         data = "&%s" % name
     self.handle_data(data)

bs4.builder._htmlparser.BeautifulSoupHTMLParser.handle_entityref = my_handle_entityref
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('AT&T announces new plans')
print soup.text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('AT&TOP announces new plans')
print soup.text
```

It produces the output:

```
AT&T announces new plans
AT&TOP announces new plans
```

You can see the method with the problem here:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py#L81

And the line with the problem here:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py#L86

Comment: Excellent, this is much better than the regex hack I wrote